# Create a JS filter form by tag for WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Please help me implement on the site (WordPress) using JavaScript a form through which you can filter articles with the specified tags (tag).

For example, a form from two drop-down lists. In the first, the user chose a1, in the second d3. After that, clicks on the "Ok" button, and goes to the address: site.com/tag/a1+d3/.

The result is the output of all the records in which the tags a1 and d3 are present.

Sorry for the quality of the translation, I use an online translator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="f1">
    <p><select name="n" id='t1'>
        <optgroup label="A">
          <option value="a1">A1</option>
          <option value="a2">A2</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="B">
          <option value="b1">B1</option>
          <option value="b2">B2</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>

      <select name="n1" id='t2'>
        <optgroup label="C">
          <option value="c1">C1</option>
          <option value="c2">C2</option>
          <option value="c3">C3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="D">
          <option value="d1">D1</option>
          <option value="d2">D2</option>
          <option value="d3">D3</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="button" onclick="f()" value="ok">
  </form>

  <script>
    function f() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // tried to connect here, but without experience and knowledge does not work
      var a = document.getElementById('t1').value;
      var b = document.getElementById('t2').value;
      var c = a + '+' + b;

      // string with parameters to send
      request.open("GET", "https://site.ru/tag/" + c);
      request.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
      request.send();
    }
  </script>

  <hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress you can use Ajax for this kind of request.

For two tags name to be send together you will need to pass them separately. Get them via $_GET in PHP file and do a search query in your database if the tags are saved in your database.

Here is working code:

```
 function f() {

      var a = document.getElementById('t1').value;
      var b = document.getElementById('t2').value;

      var c = a + '+' + b;

    //Ajac Request      
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://site.ru/tag',
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {'tag1' : a, 'tag2' :  b},
      success: function (data) {
        //do something
      }
    })
 }
```

Once you get the data back on success you can display tags data where you want.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn’t work for me at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong ?!